# Xamarin ios - build error: File not found 57x57@1x

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have ios app(Xamarin Forms). I published my app in test flight  - everything was ok.
But I updated Visual Studio to 16.3.8(Windows) and I have issue with build:

```
 File not found: /Users/admin/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/.../Icon-App-57x57@1x.png
```

I use assets. I added this file in my folder and conten.json. But I have issue

```
 File not found: /Users/admin/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/.../Icon-App-57x57@2x.png 
 File not found: /Users/admin/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/.../Icon-App-57x57@3x.png
```

I added this file, but now get error:

```
File not found: /Users/admin/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/.../Icon-App-60x60@1x.png
```

Any advice?
Do I need to manually add these files?  or is it a xamarin issue?  in the previous version, this worked.

Comment: Do you use VS on Mac or on Windows with a Mac build host?
What VS 2017 / 2019?

Comment: I use VS on Windows

Comment: I've seen this sort of thing before.  I've done things like increment the build number, clean, rebuild, delete bin/obj folders, etc.  The usual garbage you have to do with Xamarin

Comment: @FetFrumos Hi , have you solved it , does Patrick Goode's sugeestion be helpful ?